# Read text from particular block of image in python

Tags: python, django, image-processing, python-tesseract

Is there a way to reading text from an image from a specific fixed location?

```
def read_image_data(request):
    import cv2
    import pytesseract
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
    img = cv2.imread("workcenter_dash.png")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    print(text)
```

In above example I used "pytesseract" to read image text which working fine for reading text, But in my case I want read text from specificed location.

[image]

For Example: In the above image, I want to read text from only where selected with a red rectangle.

So please give me the best solutions regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fixed this issue by cropping the image then after reading its data.

It's working for me, Any better solutions for this issue so please suggest me.

```
def read_image_data(request):
    import cv2
    import pytesseract
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
    img = cv2.imread("workcenter_dash.png")
    
    height, width = img.shape[0:2]
    startRow = int(height * 0.10)
    startCol = int(width * 0.10)
    endRow = int(height * 0.90)
    endCol = int(width * 0.40)

    croppedImage = img[startRow:endRow, startCol:endCol]
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(croppedImage)
    print(text)
```